# Loading a resource with Findresource throws exception - WPF/C#

Tags: wpf, resources

I am writing a CustomControl in WPF. I have some DataTemplates in my Themes/Generic.xaml, at the resourcedictionary level, with x:Key assigned for them.

Now from within the same control class code, i want to find and load that resource so i can dynamically assing to something in the code.

I have tried base/this.FindResource("keyvalue"), this.Resources[""] etc.

It keeps returning that the resource is not found and hence null.

The resource is defenitely there in the generic.xaml.

Please help.

Answer (score 7):

A bit late for an answer, but it might benefit the others.

The resource you're trying to access is **at the theme level**, to access it from anywhere in your assembly it must be identified by ComponentResourceKey:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" 
       x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey {x:Type local:MyTVIStyleSelector}, tviBaseStyle}">
  <!-- style setters -->
</Style>
```

then in your XAML you'd reference it like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" 
       x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey {x:Type local:MyTVIStyleSelector}, tviStyle_1}"
       BasedOn={StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey {x:Type local:MyTVIStyleSelector}, tviBaseStyle}}>
  <!-- style setters -->
</Style>
```

and in your code like this:

```
ComponentResourceKey key = new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(MyTVIStyleSelector), "tviStyle_1");
Style style = (Style)Application.Current.TryFindResource(key);
```

There is also a verbose form of XAML syntax that looks like this (but its just the same thing):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" 
       x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type local:MyTVIStyleSelector}, ResourceId=tviBaseStyle}">
  <!-- style setters -->
</Style>
```

Note that even though the TypeInTargetAssembly must be set it does not restrict access to this resource for other types in assembly.

Comment: Could this technique help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528622/find-resource-from-generic-xaml-programmatically/14528823#14528823 Im trying to find an instance of resource in Generic.xaml

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have actually added the custom control as a child to another control before using the FindResource on it. I'm pretty sure that when you use FindResource, it climbs the control hierarchy until it finds a match. If your control has no parent, it will not find the resource you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can load the resource dictionary like this:

```
ResourceDictionary myDictionary = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/MyAssembly;component/Themes/Generic.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) as ResourceDictionary;
```

You can then find resources within it in the usual manner, e.g.,  myDictionary["keyvalue"]

Answer (score 1):

Since you're building a custom control I presume that you have a ControlTemplate defined in your generic.xaml file?  If so, then if you add your DataTemplate(s) to the Resources section of the ControlTemplate like this:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <!-- Data Templates Here -->
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>

    <!-- Rest of Control Template -->
</ControlTemplate>
```

then provided that the control template has been applied/loaded then you'll be able to find that data templates using a call to this.FindResource() within your control.

Answer (score 1):

x:Key and DataType are mutualy exclusiv. Internally, if you set DataType, WPF generates a key of type DataTemplateKey. So a call of FindResource with ComponentResourceKey throws an exception, because the resource can't be found with this key. Use

```
frameworkElement.FindResource(new DataTemplateKey(typeof(yourType)));
```

for a DataTemplate with DataType={x:Type local:yourType} defined or

```
frameworkElement.FindResource(new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(yourType), "ressId"));
```

for a DataTemplate with x:Key={ComponentResourceKey TypeInAssembly={x:Type l:yourType}, ResourceId=ressId} defined. Don't define DataType and x:Key in the same template.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure i think you need to define in the  of the XAML your using or the  a static resource with a new x:Key that corrisponds to what you want to change.

another option is if you use a file that contains the template merge the resources like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  <ResourceDictionary Source="SomeTemplate.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

in the appropriate place your going to try and find the resource

HTH,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

Thnaks to both.

I tried moving the resources into CT's resources section. Even then when i look up at runtime, say in OnApplyTemplate or EndInit() etc., the this.Resources has no objects in it :-( although its all ther ein the control's Generic.xaml.

So it returns null at all times.