# Find resource from Generic.xaml programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to implement [Style Binding from this article in WPF & Silverlight](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/04/19/silverlight-5-s-new-style-data-binding.aspx).

I have a resource dictionary, generic.Xaml with this code:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       <ResourceDictionary Source="/AComponent;component/Themes/MyCustomStyles.xaml" />
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Where MyCustomStyles.xaml begins like this

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

   <t:ThemeColorProvider x:Key="ThemeProvider"/>
```

I need to get the instance of ThemeProvider to update colors/brushes that I am binding to in Generic.xaml. Is it possible to get the *instance of the resource* keyed "ThemeProvider" so I can update it?

Extra credit if you know a cross platform WPF & Silverlight implementation!

Note: I need to get this *outside* of the assembly that declares Generic.xaml

Comment: What about using `FindResource` method?

Answer (score 4):

If your resource is defined in generic.xaml or any resource that is defined in MergedDictionaries in App.xaml then you need to use Application.Current.Resources, e.g.:

> BackgroundColor =
>   (Color)Application.Current.Resources["ApplicationBarBackgroundColor"]

Comment: Thanks :) we achieved this in the end using a custom MarkupExtension

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
ThemeColorProvider value= (ThemeColorProvider)FindResource("ThemeProvider");
// update value
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks  - but where is FindResource located? I need to locate this from a static (non FrameworkElement) class